# Selenium webdriver Message: no such element: Unable to locate element - iFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem when want to click on number. Using Selenium webdriver.

Here is code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromedriver_location = 'chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location)
driver.get('site')

username_input = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input'
password_input = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input'
login_submit = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/button'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(username_input).send_keys('username')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_input).send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_submit).click()

numbers = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div'
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/iframe")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(numbers).click()
```

[This is in iFrame and need to click on number 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HJtK.png)

Full xPath of number 5 is `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div`

Error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in 
> driver.find_element_by_xpath(numbers).click()
> File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
> return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
> File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
> return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
> File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HJtK.png)/div/div[3]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HJtK.png)/div[5]/div"}
> (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Also tried with

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, numbers))).click()`

Error for this is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in 
> WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, numbers))).click()
> File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch to iframe first:

```
iframe=WebDriverWait(driver,  10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/iframe")))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(numbers).click()


#REMAINING CODE TO INTERACT WITH ELEMENTS INISIDE IFRAME

#once done exit from iframe

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```